How to repeat window.print?
I want to generate pdf on the front and I am using html2pdf.js for that.
But there is a problem. It behaves differently than window.print.
window.print takes into account media print settings, while html2pdf.
Is it possible to somehow achieve the same saving as through a browser window called window.print?
my conf
  const opt = {
  margin: 0.1,
  filename,
  image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
  html2canvas: {scale: 4, useCORS: true },
  jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
  pagebreak: { mode: ['css'] },
}

html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save()

